# sdkman available to root user but not to other users

Tags: grails, sdkman

I installed sdkman as a root user using curl in CentOS 6.8 I installed Grails using sdkman and it is only available to the root user.

Do I need to install sdkman as other regular user in order for Grails to work or is there a way to use Grails I installed as a root user?

Thank you.

Comment: if you install it in `/root/bin/` e.g. then it's only there for `root`.  put it into `/usr/local/bin` e.g. for all users.

Comment: "...or is there a way to use Grails I installed as a root user" - Running Grails as root is a bad idea.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, No, no. I meant use Grails as a regular user but somehow have access to Grails.

Comment: @cfrick, So I noticed my Grails, PostgreSQL, pgAdmin3 are all not available to regular users... Do I need to move them to /usr/local/bin as well?

Comment: if your tools like `psql` are not available to all users, then many things can be wrong on that system (or right: e.g. permissions set restrictive).  if you have concrete programming problems, please formulate them. if you have questions regarding system administration then maybe the superuser SE might be a better place to ask them.

Answer (score 11):

I'd encourage you to make sdkman available to other users (look at its Docs, paragraph Custom Installation, add init script that sources init file from `$SDKMAN_DIR/bin` directory).

Then have users who want Grails install it.

Or install Grails via its repository (accepting, that this will be an older version than one from SDKMAN).

In my case I used:

1. `export SDKMAN_DIR="/usr/local/sdkman" && curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash` - make sure $SDKMAN_DIR doesn't exist before you install sdkman as it will be overwritten otherwise
2. In `.bashrc` files for users I wanted to be able to use sdkman. AT THE VERY END of these otherwise, it may not work

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="/usr/local/sdkman"
[[ -s "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Docs: https://sdkman.io/install

Comment: source .bashrc
-bash: export: `[[': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]]': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 2):

3. For non-interactive shell add into .profile

   **export SDKMAN_DIR="/usr/local/sdkman"**

   **[[ -s "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"**